# How to add custom model to django_celery

Tags: django, python-2.7, celery, django-celery

I'm working on making celery suitable for high availability I've forked the [django_celery](https://github.com/celery/django-celery) project and this fork of [celery](https://github.com/celery/celery/compare/3.1...Awingu:awingu-3.1.23) in order to make the customizations that I need. The celery link shows the modifications to the beat.py that utilizes the following code:

I've added this Lock model to django_celery models.py file and was able to migrate just fine:

```
from django.db import models

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Lock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _('locks')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In celery in the utils folder I've added this locked.py file:

```
from djcelery.models import Lock
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.db import transaction, IntegrityError


class Locked(object):
    """A context manager to add a distributed mutex."""

    def __init__(self, name, timeout):
        self.name = name
        self.lock = None
        self.timeout = timeout

    def __enter__(self):
        # first delete any expired locks
        expired = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(seconds=self.timeout)
        Lock.objects.filter(name=self.name, created__lte=expired).delete()
        # then try to get the lock
        try:
            Lock(name=self.name).save()
        except IntegrityError:
            transaction.rollback()
            raise LockError('Could not acquire lock: {0}'.format(self.name))

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        Lock.objects.filter(name=self.name).delete()


class LockError(Exception):
    """Exception thrown when the requested lock already exists."""

    pass
```

with these changes I'm able to run the following commands:

```
celery worker
python manage.py runserver
python manage.py shell
```

I issues arrises when I try to run the scheduler:

```
celery beat
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "venv/bin/celery", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('celery', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/bin/celery.py", line 81, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/bin/celery.py", line 793, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/bin/base.py", line 311, in execute_from_commandline
    return self.handle_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:])
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/bin/celery.py", line 785, in handle_argv
    return self.execute(command, argv)
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/bin/celery.py", line 717, in execute
    ).run_from_argv(self.prog_name, argv[1:], command=argv[0])
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/bin/base.py", line 315, in run_from_argv
    sys.argv if argv is None else argv, command)
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/bin/base.py", line 377, in handle_argv
    return self(*args, **options)
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/bin/base.py", line 274, in __call__
    ret = self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/bin/beat.py", line 72, in run
    beat = partial(self.app.Beat,
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 325, in __get__
    value = obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = self.__get(obj)
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/app/base.py", line 572, in Beat
    return self.subclass_with_self('celery.apps.beat:Beat')
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/app/base.py", line 504, in subclass_with_self
    Class = symbol_by_name(Class)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 96, in symbol_by_name
    module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/apps/beat.py", line 19, in <module>
    from celery import VERSION_BANNER, platforms, beat
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/beat.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .utils.locked import Locked, LockError
  File "/venv/src/celery/celery/utils/locked.py", line 1, in <module>
    from djcelery.models import Lock
  File "/venv/src/django-celery/djcelery/models.py", line 30, in <module>
    class TaskMeta(models.Model):
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 105, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 237, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I have djcelery in my `INSTALLED_APPS` setting so I don't know what is going on at this point?

Answer (score 1):

You must specify app instance to use for the celery command

> -A APP, --app=APP     app instance to use (e.g. module.attr_name)

For example if i have structure

```
pybilling
- pybilling
  - celeryconfig.py
```

then i should start celery beat with the command

```
celery --app pybilling.celeryconfig:app beat
```

Here is the contents of celeryconfig.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'pybilling.settings')

from django.conf import settings  # noqa

app = Celery('pybilling')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Celery is often used with Django and is compatible with Django but is is not *inherently* a Django application. The modifications you've made are such that when you run `celery beat`, Django models are loaded. In order to be able to use the models, the applications must be initialized first. The standard way to do this is to call [`django.setup()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage) *after* having set things so that Django's code can find the Django settings. It could be something like:

```
import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")
django.setup()
```

You need to change `project.settings` to the actual module name that contains the settings.